# Error parsing XML, line 337, column 62: The reference to entity "appId" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

Am trying to add facebook login to my website using javascript SDK.

```
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src =     "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=1502856099942926&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

When I add the above code and save it to my website code, am getting the error:
Error parsing XML, line 337, column 62: The reference to entity "appId" must end with the ';' delimiter.

How to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src =     &quot;//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;appId=1502856099942926&amp;version=v2.0&quot;;
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, &#039;script&#039;, &#039;facebook-jssdk&#039;));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the & characters in the url with & and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code before your code

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your-app-id', // App ID
      status     : true, // login status
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML          
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies

    });
  };
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This too is showing me the same error

Answer (score 0):

instead of put all in a single expression like this:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=1502856099942926&version=v2.0";
```

use FB.init function so you will not have any problems with the quots.

just put your own configuration like this:

```
<!-- facebook -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOU_APP_ID', // App ID
      xfbml      : true, // parse XFBML
      version    : 'v2.0' // sdk version           
    });
    // Additional initialization code here
  };
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<!-- /facebook -->
```

Reference (for more info in details):  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using blogger then use a Blogger HTML Converter. It worked for me with the recommendation feed of fb. 
ex original:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=[APP ID]&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

ex after translation:

```
&lt;div id=&quot;fb-root&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;script&gt;(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = &quot;//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;appId=[APP ID]&amp;version=v2.0&quot;;
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, &#039;script&#039;, &#039;facebook-jssdk&#039;));&lt;/script&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its so simple dear. 
The problem is that you are selecting HTML5 while generating facebook app on facebook. Just Click on "IFRAME" and your problem is solved. :)
See screenshot for more. [here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YD8k.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
//<![CDATA[
paste your plugin code here
//]]>
```